# Twilio/TwiML: Call hangs up abruptly after processing webhook url

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I am working on processing a simple end to end call in Twilio using TwiMl bin. I am facing issues after I process the  verb using a webhook url. Once the url is processed, the call abruptly hangs up without processing the next steps defined in the TwiML bin. Attached is the screenshot of my TwiMl bin along with the webhook url

[TwiML Bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVxxA.png)

[webhook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1IOo.png)

The code executes correctly till the  verb. Post webhook hook execution I expect the call to get passed on the TwiMl bin and process Can you help me with your current location but that doesn't happen instead the call hangs up.

Comment: You should paste the code in your question instead of just posting a screen shot picture. Please consider: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The recording action URL is not returning additional TwiML to keep  the call up.

Reference here.
TwiML Record Verb
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#attributes-action

When the recording finishes, Twilio requests TwiML from your action URL, it doesn’t continue on with the contents of the existing TwiM Bin.

Since you are only return a single Say verb, the call ends after that.

You can investigate the TwiML Redirect verb and another TwiML Bin to continue the exchange.

Alan